# How to add a PHTML, CSS & JS to CMS Page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, frontend, phtml

The process was pretty straight forward for previous version of Magento. All I had to do was create .phmtl page in **app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\page** and add js/css in **js** dir of root.

I can't seem to understand the process in Magento 2. Can anyone please give a step by step procedure for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the dev docs and you´ll find it out ;)

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_debug.html